# How to divide a panel into 2 panels by using cardLayout?

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, cardlayout

I tried to divide a big panel into 2 panels and display them in the big pannel but it didn't work..However, when I played the program, it just showed last panel, even though the 2 panels are set to different locations.

```
public class PaperScissorRock extends JFrame implements Runnable {


ImageIcon[] gameIcons= {new ImageIcon("C:\\Jsp\\HelloJava\\src\\Images\\r.png"),new ImageIcon("C:\\Jsp\\HelloJava\\src\\Images\\s.png"),new ImageIcon("C:\\Jsp\\HelloJava\\src\\Images\\p.png")};
JLabel me=new JLabel("Me");
JLabel com=new JLabel("Computer");
JButton[] jb=new JButton[3];//
CardLayout psrLayout=new CardLayout();/


PaperScissorRock()
{


    JPanel bigPanel=new JPanel(psrLayout);//A panel to include 2 panels(northP/southP)
    JPanel northP=new JPanel();
    northP.setLayout(null);
    northP.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
    northP.setBounds(400, 150, 400, 50);//
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        jb[i]=new JButton(gameIcons[i]);
        jb[i].setSize(10, 10);
        northP.add(jb[i], BorderLayout.NORTH);
    }


    JPanel southP=new JPanel();
    southP.setLayout(null);
    southP.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    southP.setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    southP.setBounds(400, 100, 400, 100);
    southP.add(me, BorderLayout.SOUTH);southP.add(com, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    bigPanel.setBounds(400, 150, 400, 450);
    bigPanel.add(northP, "nbp");bigPanel.add(southP, "sbp");
    psrLayout.show(bigPanel, "nbp");//this is not called(?)
    psrLayout.show(bigPanel, "sbp");


    Game.Gframe.add(bigPanel);



}
```

In the bigPanel, I want to display two panels(northP/southP) simultaneously.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) One way to get image(s) for an example is to hot link to images seen in [this Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19209650/418556). But perhaps giving the different panels a different color or visible border will suffice here. 3) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 4) Don't mix layouts with `null` or 'no' layouts - use layouts for all.

Comment: 5) **But you seem to be trying to use a `CardLayout` as if it was a `GridLayout` (or a number of different types of layouts, in fact) which can each display multiple components *at the same instant*. That is not how a card layout is designed to work. It displays exactly one 'card' at a time.**

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) for examples of how the various layout managers work.